# OpenGL, GLSL: Garbage values in uniforms

Tags: linux, opengl, glsl, shader, glut

My problem is very similar to, if not the same as, this: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/169185-glUniform1f()-seems-broken-where-is-the-error

Except it's not limited just to the glUniform1f function. Basically, **any** uniform passed to the GLSL program gets a total garbage value for no apparent reason. A call to glGetUniformfv also confirms that. Hardcoding the expected values into the shader produces the intended results. What could possibly go wrong?

I haven't been able to find any relevant information on this subject except for the provided link, which didn't help me at all.

The C code:

```
void display(void) {
    double time = get_time() - g_starttime;
    double delta = time - g_lasttime;

    printf("%f [%f]\n", time, delta);    

    GLint m_viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, m_viewport);
    printf("%i, %i, %i, %i\n", m_viewport[0], m_viewport[1], m_viewport[2], m_viewport[3]);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glUseProgram(g_prog);
    glUniform2f(u_view, (float)m_viewport[2], (float)m_viewport[3]);
    glUniform1f(u_time, (float)time);
    glRectf(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();

    g_lasttime = time;
}
```

The GLSL fragment shader (there is no vertex shader):

```
#version 120

uniform vec2 view;
uniform float time;

void main(void) {
    vec2 pos = vec2(gl_FragCoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(pos.x/view.x, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**EDIT**: I've also added a basic vertex shader, as Aki Suihkonen suggested. It didn't help.

```
#version 120

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the cast from GLint to float will work as you expect. it might be, that the integer bits are simply but inside a float, which would lead to strange mantisse/exponent values in the float. could you declare m_viewport as a GLfloat instead?

Comment: Just did that (and s/glGetIntegerv/glGetFloatv/, of course), as I expected it changed nothing. The thing is, "time" doesn't work properly either, even when I use it in the shader.

Comment: @NicolBolas NVidia GeForce GTX 680. I've successfully ran a few glsl shader samples (for example http://joshbeam.com/articles/getting_started_with_glsl/). I also took part in development of a game that makes use of them, and it runs perfectly here as well. I can't spot a difference between my approach and what I've seen in other people's code. Oh, and my driver version is 310.14 (beta).

Comment: Tried glGetError? Please show your shader loading code, specifically where u_view/u_time come from.

Comment: @Tim: here's the whole thing: http://pastebin.com/5zZab0Zk
As for glGetError, I didn't try it yet. Where exactly should I do that?

Comment: @twall Huh? In which way should casting a `GLint` to a `Glfloat` be anything different from casting an `int` to a `float`, which, as you know, doesn't do anything with binary reinterpretation. The case would be different had he used `glUniform2fv` which expects a pointer to a float. But casting an int to a float works like everywhere else in C and as expected here.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure I GLfloat was a type of its own, or if it was just a alias for float. If GLfloat wouldn't have had a proper casting operator, this might have failed. Or at least, so I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I've also witnessed some strange behavior with shaders and especially shader compilers. They don't seem to be that tolerant to e.g. unused variables. Or with webGL Opera's shader compiler didn't even compile when a certain variable was used in both vertex and fragment shader (and for a perfectly valid reason).

Perhaps you should include also a vertex shader instead of default one.

I'm afraid, that the technology isn't that mature yet...

One more thing: how is "u_view" initialized? I'm only accustomed of assigning u_view a handle from the compiler...

Comment: I guess I'll try adding a vertex shader after all, I was avoiding doing that because my program is very small and only supposed to function as a 2D fragment shader playground for me. I'll post results when I'm done.

Comment: My first advice is to remove 'time' as it's unused. And then go for the more tedious ones.

Comment: Already tried removing unused uniforms (and making use of them as well), no effect at all.

Comment: Oh, and as for u_* stuff: it's just plain `u_view = glGetUniformLocation(g_prog, "view");`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have fixed this already, but you may need to add some checks before setting the uniforms:

When you obtain the index to the uniform it can fail where the uniform is not used and has been optimized out by the compiler. In the test case for u_time is not used. An example function to get the uniform index is below. Only set the value of the uniform if you can get a valid location (i.e. it is being used or hasn't been optimized out)

```
bool findUniformLocation( const String& name, UInt32& location )
    {
        printGLSLLog(m_program);
        CHECK_GL_ERROR;
        location = (UInt32)glGetUniformLocation( m_program, name.c_str() );

        printGLSLLog(m_program);
        CHECK_GL_ERROR;

        return ( location != (UInt32)-1 );
    }
```

The garbage may therefore be being caused by you setting the value on u_time which is an incorrect index or possibly the same as the u_view essentially setting a garbaged value